# Remove indexes (1,2,3..) from the json file data and convert into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This is the json file.

```
{
    "1": {
        "Order Number": "CA-2017-126221",
        "Order Status": "Completed",
        "Order Date": "30/12/2017",
        "First Name (Billing)": "Abdul",
        "State Code (Shipping)": "SD",
        "Postcode (Shipping)": "75100",
        "Shipping Method Title": "Free shipping",
        "Payment Method Title": "Cash on delivery"
    },
    "2": {
        "Order Number": "CA-2017-143259",
        "Order Status": "Completed",
        "Order Date": "30/12/2017",
        "City (Shipping)": "Sanghar",
        "State Code (Shipping)": "SD",
        "Postcode (Shipping)": "68100",
        "Shipping Method Title": "Free shipping",
        "Payment Method Title": "Cash on delivery"
    }
}
```

I want to remove these ids 1,2,3 etc outside the object from the json file and convert into an array so i can access the values using .map() method in react.

Comment: Consider parsing the JSON? `JSON.parse`, then you can access it like a normal object.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. _“I want”_ is not a question. Show what you tried, explain what your actual problem was/is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```js
let a={
    "1": {
        "Order Number": "CA-2017-126221",
        "Order Status": "Completed",
        "Order Date": "30/12/2017",
        "First Name (Billing)": "Abdul",
        "State Code (Shipping)": "SD",
        "Postcode (Shipping)": "75100",
        "Shipping Method Title": "Free shipping",
        "Payment Method Title": "Cash on delivery"
    },
    "2": {
        "Order Number": "CA-2017-143259",
        "Order Status": "Completed",
        "Order Date": "30/12/2017",
        "City (Shipping)": "Sanghar",
        "State Code (Shipping)": "SD",
        "Postcode (Shipping)": "68100",
        "Shipping Method Title": "Free shipping",
        "Payment Method Title": "Cash on delivery"
    }
}
console.log(Object.values(a));

//OR

let data=[];
for(i in a){
  data.push(a[i])
}
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const json = {
    "1": {
        "Order Number": "CA-2017-126221",
        "Order Status": "Completed",
        "Order Date": "30/12/2017",
        "First Name (Billing)": "Abdul",
        "State Code (Shipping)": "SD",
        "Postcode (Shipping)": "75100",
        "Shipping Method Title": "Free shipping",
        "Payment Method Title": "Cash on delivery"
    },
    "2": {
        "Order Number": "CA-2017-143259",
        "Order Status": "Completed",
        "Order Date": "30/12/2017",
        "City (Shipping)": "Sanghar",
        "State Code (Shipping)": "SD",
        "Postcode (Shipping)": "68100",
        "Shipping Method Title": "Free shipping",
        "Payment Method Title": "Cash on delivery"
    }
};

console.log(Object.values(json))
```

You can use `Object.values()` but first you need to `JSON.parse()` the json.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.values()` on the data you have. It will get you all the values of the immediate keys:

```js
const data = {
    "1": {
        "Order Number": "CA-2017-126221",
        "Order Status": "Completed",
        "Order Date": "30/12/2017",
        "First Name (Billing)": "Abdul",
        "State Code (Shipping)": "SD",
        "Postcode (Shipping)": "75100",
        "Shipping Method Title": "Free shipping",
        "Payment Method Title": "Cash on delivery"
    },
    "2": {
        "Order Number": "CA-2017-143259",
        "Order Status": "Completed",
        "Order Date": "30/12/2017",
        "City (Shipping)": "Sanghar",
        "State Code (Shipping)": "SD",
        "Postcode (Shipping)": "68100",
        "Shipping Method Title": "Free shipping",
        "Payment Method Title": "Cash on delivery"
    }
};

const vals = Object.values(data);

console.log(vals)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `Object.entries()` and `reduce()`.

```js
const data = {
    "1": {
        "Order Number": "CA-2017-126221",
        "Order Status": "Completed",
        "Order Date": "30/12/2017",
        "First Name (Billing)": "Abdul",
        "State Code (Shipping)": "SD",
        "Postcode (Shipping)": "75100",
        "Shipping Method Title": "Free shipping",
        "Payment Method Title": "Cash on delivery"
    },
    "2": {
        "Order Number": "CA-2017-143259",
        "Order Status": "Completed",
        "Order Date": "30/12/2017",
        "City (Shipping)": "Sanghar",
        "State Code (Shipping)": "SD",
        "Postcode (Shipping)": "68100",
        "Shipping Method Title": "Free shipping",
        "Payment Method Title": "Cash on delivery"
    }
};

const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((a, c) => ([...a, c[1]]), []);

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!